# MongoDB unique compound index on nested array

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have following document:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a4142699f6e958126baa794"),
        "name" : "doc7",
        "nestedObjects" : [
                {
                        "val" : 15
                },
                {
                        "val" : 16
                },
                {
                        "val" : 15
                }
        ]
}
```

What would be the spell in MongoDB shell to enforce uniqueness of "val" values in nestedObjects array, within a particular doc, so  name/val combinations should be unique?

so far I tried db.test.docs.ensureIndex({"name":1, "val": 1}, {unique: true})
and db.test.docs.createIndex({"name":1, "val": 1}, {unique: true}) but nothing seems to work. When I try to insert:

```
db.test.docs.find().forEach(function(doc){
    db.test.docs.update({_id: doc._id}, {$push:{"nestedObjects": {val: 15}}})});
```

Mongo DB doesn't mind that...

Comment: How about trying to use $addToSet ? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/index.html

Comment: it would work if an element pushed is atomic type...but what if I want to push embedded object like {val:15, golden: true} and if   {val:15, golden: false} being pushed further - I want it to fail due to unique constraint on val and name...

Comment: @KonstantinRybakov - Were you able to solve this issue ?